# PHP sort array's indexes with respective values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm a newbie when it comes to PHP and even after some searches, I can't quite figure out the proper way to sort out my array. By sort, I don't mean the values but the array indexes along with their respective values.

I have an average temperature array, that has the hour (0-23) as the array index, and the array values gets added within a loop like so:

```
 $tempAvg[date('H', strtotime($currenttime))] = ($temp / 12);
```

And this would create an array like this:

```
[11] 21.07
[12] 20.7
...
[23] 20.8
[0] 21.1
[1] 22.4
[2] 20.6
```

So what I'd like to do, is sort/arrange the indexes so the array would be like this:

```
[0] 21.1
[1] 22.4
[2] 20.6
[11] 21.07
[12] 20.7
...
[23] 20.8
```

The reason I need to do this is so I can later turn it into a JSON format that my chart can read easier.
I hope I'm making sense. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [`ksort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) https://3v4l.org/6rftm

Comment: @Nick Man do I feel dumb right now. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries at all - we've all been there... :)